# MICROSOFT COGNITIVE FACE API PERSONGROUP

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a person-group using MS Cognitive face API but I keep getting the error message "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"BadArgument\",\"message\":\"Request body is invalid.\"}}". I know it is a problem with the body I'm passing. Below is my source code. Would be glad if anybody could help me solve this.

```
    public async Task<dynamic> CREATEPERSONGROUP()
    {
        var get = await MakeRequest();
        var response = get;
        return Json(data: response);
    }

    static async Task<string> MakeRequest()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

        // Request headers
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key",           
           subscriptionKey);

        var uri = "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
        /face/v1.0/persongroups/rwtfacesearchgroup1?" + queryString;

        HttpResponseMessage response;

        // Request body
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("name: searching");

        using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
        {
            content.Headers.ContentType = new 
            MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            response = await client.PutAsync(uri, content);
            string contentString = await 
            response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return (contentString);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I noticed that your data `byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("name: searching");` is encoded in json, but isn't actually valid json.  Valid json would look like this: `{ "name" : "searching"}`  https://jsonlint.com/ will help you out.

Comment: I get the error "can not convert the method group "GetBytes" to non-delegate type byte"  when I put it this way { "name" : "searching"}

Comment: I just tested `byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\"name\": \"searching\"}");` and it worked fine...  Maybe you were missing the escape characters?

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. I missed the escape characters.